# MongoDB - mulitiple fields, optional values, one query

Tags: mongodb

I can’t get to query multiple optional values on several fields. Here is my code:

```
if (query1 || query2 || query3 || query4) {

      const examples = await db

         .collection("examples")

         .find({

            $or: [

               {

                  $text: { $search: `${query1}` },

               },

               { field2: query2 },

               { field3: query3 },

               { field4: { $gte: Number(query4) } },

            ],

            verified: true,

         })

         .project({ anotherField: 0})

         .sort({ createdAt: -1 })

         .toArray();

      return {

         props: {

            examples: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(examples)),

         },

      };

   }
```

I receive the following error message:

> MongoServerError: error processing query: ns=examplesdb.examplesTree:
> $and $or field3 $eq null field2 $eq “some-keyword” field4 $gte nan.0
> TEXT : query=undefined, language=english, caseSensitive=0,
> diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL verified $eq true Sort: { createdAt: -1
> } Proj: { anotherField: 0 } planner returned error :: caused by :: No
> query solutions

Expected outcome:
Whichever query1 or 2 or 3 or 4 comes in, I want mongodb to find that document where query1 or 2 or 3 or 4 matches with $text or field2 or field3 or field4 (respectively).

The important thing is that the query1/2/3/4 are optional and sometimes all of them would be used, sometimes only 2 and so on… So my question points at $or as well.

I already know that $text search can’t be used with $or. And I’m on the free tier at the moment so I can’t use aggregation either (due to limitations, it returns that error message).

What else should I try? Please someone lead me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: What if `query4` is null, the condition becomes `field4`  > `null`, which is not a valid condition

Comment: use javascript, to construct the query dynamically. MongoDB queries are JSON so you can add fields, push members to arrays etc based on user input

Comment: @CharchitKapoor how to ignore invalid conditions? Just return the valid ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
let filter = {};

if (query1) filter = { ...filter, $text: { $search: `${query1}` } };
if (query2) filter = { ...filter, field2: query2 };
if (query3) filter = { ...filter, field3: query3 };
if (query4) filter = { ...filter, field4: { $gte: Number(query4) } };

const examples = await db
  .collection('examples')
  .find(filter)
  .project({ anotherField: 0 })
  .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
  .toArray();

return {
  props: {
    examples: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(examples)),
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know I can query like this.